# listener issues in oracle 19c

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, listener, tnsnames, containers

These are my listener.ora and tnsnames.ora files

```
listener.ora



SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
      (SID_DESC =
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME = dr_DGMGRL)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/dbhome_1)
      (SID_NAME = dr)
      (UR=A)
    )
  )
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.XX.XX)(PORT = 1521))
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.XX.XX)(PORT = 1521))
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = /u01/app/oracle


tnsname.ora


DR =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.XX.XX)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = dr) (UR=A)
    )
  )


PDB1 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.XX.XX)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = pdb1)
    )
  )


PDB2 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.XX.XX)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = pdb2)
    )
  )

PDB3 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.XX.XX)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = pdb3)
    )
  )
```

when I start the listener, only getting this output:

```
lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on 23-JAN-2024 20:38:21

Copyright (c) 1991, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.XX.XX)(PORT=1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Start Date                23-JAN-2024 20:28:41
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 9 min. 39 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/hostname/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.XX.XX)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.XX.XX)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "dr_DGMGRL" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "dr", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

Comment: what is your problem? status: UNKNOWN means that your listener resource was registered statically via config file. If you want to see more, you have to set parameter "local_listener" in database and execute `ALTER SYSTEM REGISTER`. (or just wait).

Comment: Thanks! It's working!